# woocommerce add action after user registered

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

Does someone know a hook to add an action after user registered on woocommerce or wordpress?

My aim is to add a short code of javascript on site header after user is registered on my woocommerce site, something like this :

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'my_register_save' );

function my_register_save( $user_id ){

    add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_account_creation', 10, 1 );
    do_action('wp_head', $user_id);
}

function my_account_creation( $arg ){

    /* Confirmation création de compte */
    $output = "<script> xxx my script xxx </script>";

    return $output;

}
```

Does [user register](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) is the right hook? because when i use this code i get a fatal error.

Thank you guys.

Comment: I always prefer to use native function, though you said that you using woocommerce so use this hook `woocommerce_created_customer`  as the syntax of hook from woocommerce as `do_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', $customer_id, $new_customer_data, $password_generated );`

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply, so i can add script with wp_head hook? with this?

Comment: you can't just return output with a function fired by an action. You can only do that with filters. You should use `wp_enqueue_script` to add javascript to the front end.